# Android: Possible to get hover usb mouse coordinates? (without any clicks)

Tags: android, hover, coordinates, mouse

I need to get mouse coordinates with just hovering the usb mouse above my app's view.

the function `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {` only works when I actually click the mouse.

any way to do it?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set an OnHoverListener via setOnHoverListener.  Its mainly meant for styluses, but it may work with a mouse as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the emulator knows, there's no such thing as a mouse. I'm assuming you want this for testing purposes, but as far as the emulator is concerned, you're basically asking the device to track your finger without touching the screen.

Comment: Yes indeed, but I don't care much about the emulator. My Android Device is a development board with dual Android 5.1/Linux roms with a standard USB mouse connected. So I just wonder if there is a work to make it work there.